# My 13 month old baby refuses to stand

Tags: toddler, walking, standing

She will stand when it suits her, whilst holding on to the sofa or other furniture, and yesterday she stood without support for about 5 seconds.

(She’s also a bloody good climber, she climbs on the sofa, units, stairs.... you name it.)

So that we can practice with her, we try to stand her up, balance her and catch her etc, but when you pick her up to try and stand her up.... she’ll flop her legs and refuses to stand.

Anything we can do to get her to stop?

Comment: Are you worried there's something wrong, that she's behind, or tired of her not walking on her own? In other words, *why* do you want her to stand/want to encourage her to stand alone? Within ranges, kids normally develop at the pace that is "comfortable" for them physically. She drops down because she's not comfortable with it yet. They walk soon enough.

Answer (score 5):

I’m a big fan of child led learning, and by that I mean let the child find what interests her and do that.

Are you worried she’s not developing right?  If so, ask her pediatrician. Otherwise, she will decide to stand (and then walk) when she decides that she has a reason to do so! Let her do what’s interesting for her, and trust that she’ll get around to standing and walking soon enough. Standing is interesting and fun, and she’ll want to do it!

You can of course make sure she has a good environment - one with *some* supported standing, but also plenty of floor space to stand, and plenty of stuff in that area for her to get to.

In terms of milestones, 13 months is fine for ‘can stand independently for a few seconds’.  See [this list](https://www.adam-mila.com/milestones/gross-motor-skills/standing/) for example; the next milestone is 11-14 months which she is still in. So I wouldn’t be worried yet that it’s a problem - but always ask your pediatrician if you have any concerns.